# Replacing attribute table entries using Python script

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator

I am using ArcMap 10 from ArcGIS 10.2.1 package.

I got an attribute table, with few collumns. I need to replace some column "String_A" entries with newer "String_B" entries, in the same row. 
In both "String_A" and "String_B" columns are some  values. 
Some entries in column "String_A" dont need to be changed, only those, where "String_B" entries not . 
Both columns are strings.

I am doing it by hand for now, but it would be nice to have a script in Python that can do it for me, because from time to time I need to update table with some new entries.

I am learning Python, but with my knowledge for today I can't do this task. 
So, I need some help with Field calculator and Python.

From "String_B" to "String_A" replace entries, example in the picture:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding, you want to replace values in field A with values from column B when the value in field A doesn't match the value in field B, is that correct? If so, you don't really need a python script. Simply select all values where field A <> field B (or alternately, select where field A = field B and then switch selection). Then run Field Calculator on Field A, setting it equal to field B. Field Calculator will only run on the records you selected.

I apologize if that's not what you meant. If you still want python code, post that and you shall have it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It helped! Exactly what I needed.